# Can't use select2 in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, jquery-select2

I'm trying to use select2 in my Laravel project. I downloaded the `select2.min.css` and `select2.min.js` files. And I paste this files into my public/css and public/js folders. In the blade files, I added this scripts to load select2 files:

```
<link type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/select2.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{{ asset('js/select2.min.js') }}"></script>
```

I inspect elements in browser and it's successfully loaded. But, I can't use it.

Here's the select and options from blade file:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('tags', 'Tags') }}
    <select class="form-control select2-tags" name="tags" multiple="multiple">
        @foreach ($tags as $tag)
            <option value="{{ $tag->id }}">{{ $tag->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

And here's the scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.select2-tags').select2();
</script>
```

It's successfully bring the tags, but it's simple select form. I want to select2 form.

It's really weird issue. Everything seems to right, but didn't work. Can anyone know, why it didn't work.

Comment: I don't see you are loading jquery anywhere?

Comment: app.js file is already loading jquery. And the script is in the app.blade.php file.

Comment: OK, then another question. Is `app.js` loaded before `<script src="{{ asset('js/select2.min.js') }}"></script>` ?

Comment: Yes, it loaded before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey I solved the problem. Problem is the `defer` in script tag.

I changed the `<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>` to `<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>`. And it worked.